# Google Cloud Endpoint : Request params not delivered to Cloud Endpoints when using Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Suddenly my gapi client stopped sending request params to endpoint.
This is how my code looks like

1. Load the gapi JS
   https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initGoogleApis
2. in initGoogleApis

> function initGoogleApis() {
>
> ```
> var ROOT = HOST + "/_ah/api";
>
> gapi.client.load("userendpoint", "v1", function() {
>     userendpoint = gapi.client.userendpoint;
>     }, ROOT); }
> ```

3. Now when I query `userendpoint.<some function>`, then it is not passing the request params to endpoint

NOTE: it was working fine till today morning.

Anyone else facing the same issue? (this might be due to some update in the gapi library)

Comment: Maybe @dan-holevoet can take a look at this issue?
It looks like the gapi.client has trouble with serializing objects or the Google API infrastructure can't deserialize them. However in our application the objects are not sent so it looks like it's a serialization issue.

Comment: My sources tell me that this issue is beeing worked on with high priority.

Comment: Looks like someone woke up: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/t9GElAJwj8U

Comment: the issue has been fixed now

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved as of yesterday 2014-09-23 08:00 (US Pacific Time).
Details about this issue can be found in the [Google App Engine Downtime Notify Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/t9GElAJwj8U)

However 'Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript' is still in Beta and breaking changes have been rolled out more than once. Clound Endpoints themselves are out of beta and can be used for production use.

Now, to properly answer this questions:
The simple advice here is: Don't use beta products for production applications.
To avoid problems with Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript, just don't use it. You can write your own REST API client that will not be affected by changes to the JavaScript library from Google. I have done this for testing purposes a couple of times and it is not hard, just a lot of work depending on how many endpoints you have and how complex they are.

Comment: I don't agree with your advice. Beta means it can't change, but get a temporary outage you can get it everywhere, especially when reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Mario In the case of Google APIs my experience is that APIs can and will change until they are out of beta. Once they are final they stick to their deprecation schedule. I don't mean to reinvent the wheel. There are libraries to help you in creating a RESP API client (but this would be out of scope for this question). Recent events led me to believe that this particular bit of the JavaScript API cannot be trusted for production use with Cloud Endpoints. It's your choice whether you can live with the downtimes that were and will be in the future. My point is: There are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem on two projects.
I think that Google has deoployed a new version of the "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js" and it dosen't works as expected...

We need to open a ticket to Google support. If I have any news I will report them to you.

Google reports (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/t9GElAJwj8U):
We are currently experiencing an issue with Google Cloud Endpoints where the GAPI Javascript client is unable to pass request parameters.  For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any inconvenience you may be experiencing. We will provide an update by Tuesday, 2014-09-23 05:00 (all times are in US/Pacific) with current details, and if available an estimated time for resolution.

Update:
We have fixed the issue affecting Google Cloud Endpoints JavaScript client and are gradually rolling-out a fixed version. We estimate full resolution of the issue by 06:30 US/Pacific Pacific. We will provide an update by 06:00 AM.

Update:
Now it works for me.

Marco

Comment: I have re-opened a issue with google  do follow it here 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=147

Comment: @ShankarSinghKotuli The referenced issue is very old and something very different.